# spyOn a variable's value - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is it possible to spy on a variable's value?

I am wanting to check that a variable's value has changed after I perform a function, ie:

**app.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
    var someVar = '';

    myfunct() {
      this.someVar = 'hello world';
    }
}
```

**app.spec.ts**

```
let component: AppComponent

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: []
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

it('should equal hello world', () => {
  component.myFunct();
  expect(component.someVar).toEqual('hello world');

});
```

Comment: Yes, did you test your code before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but you don't need a jasmine spy for that!

I generally like to split up my angular tests into two categories:

- TestBed tests (which are like the ones above that check UI changes)
- Non-TestBed tests that test pure logic of the component.

I make this distinction because I find that TestBed tests are slower to write and slower to execute on the build server (especially if you have a lot of tests).

Your example (if I understand it correctly) falls in the Non-TestBed category as there are no UI changes (like bindings and stuff) to be checked.

A test could look like this:

**example.component.ts**

```
export class ExampleComponent {
    public someVar: string;

    constructor() {
       this.someVar = "";
    }

    public someFunction() {
       this.someVar = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

**example.component.spec.ts**

```
 describe("ExampleComponent", () => {
   let component: ExampleComponent;
   describe("When the component is initialized", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        component = new ExampleComponent();
      });

      it("should have a variable someVar that is empty"), () => {
        expect(component.someVar).toEqual("");
      });

      describe("And when someFunction is called", () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            component.someFunction();
        });

        it("should have a variable someVar that is 'Hello World'"), () => {
            expect(component.someVar).toEqual("Hello World");
        });
    });
  });
});
```